# <?php// gives unexpected behaviour

Tags: php

When placing a comment directly after the php tag I get unexpected behaviour and no errors.

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting( E_ALL ); 
?>

<?php//no space after causes unexpected behaviour and no error indication
echo "this won't show up in browser";
?>

<?php //a space will allow expected behaviour
echo "Works as expected, displays in browser";
?>
```

Comment: Then put a space after it

Comment: That is because `<?php` has no semicolon indicating the end of a line. Without the space, you're essentially **combining** the two lines as into one: `<?phpecho`. That's a syntax error, and will not flag the code as PHP at all.

Comment: no error and no actual php, bet the output is in the browser

Comment: @ObsidianAge no syntax error because it was never run as php ?

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#118827

Comment: Thanks ShiraNia7.  That helps explain the syntax requirements.

Comment: I added this 'question' to hopefully help other newer developers.  This didn't give an error and it took a while to debug what was causing my code to not run as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given the parser a chance to even see the opening PHP tag because you've defiled it with your comment. It doesn't even realize you're writing PHP yet.

Most of PHP syntax is actually defined within the documentation comments for some reason. You can see that whitespace is required in: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#118827